# Gem to wrap API can't make API key setter work in all classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I have a Ruby gem which wraps an API. I have two classes: `Client` and `Season` with a `Configuration` module. But I can't access a change to the API Key, Endpoint made via `Client` in the `Season` class.

My `ApiWrapper` module looks like this:

```
require "api_wrapper/version"
require 'api_wrapper/configuration'
require_relative "api_wrapper/client"
require_relative "api_wrapper/season"

module ApiWrapper
    extend Configuration
end
```

My `Configuration` module looks like this:

```
module ApiWrapper
   module Configuration
       VALID_CONNECTION_KEYS = [:endpoint, :user_agent, :method].freeze
       VALID_OPTIONS_KEYS    = [:api_key, :format].freeze
       VALID_CONFIG_KEYS     = VALID_CONNECTION_KEYS + VALID_OPTIONS_KEYS

       DEFAULT_ENDPOINT    = 'http://defaulturl.com'
       DEFAULT_METHOD      = :get

       DEFAULT_API_KEY      = nil
       DEFAULT_FORMAT       = :json


       attr_accessor *VALID_CONFIG_KEYS

      def self.extended(base)
        base.reset
      end

      def reset
          self.endpoint   = DEFAULT_ENDPOINT
          self.method     = DEFAULT_METHOD
          self.user_agent = DEFAULT_USER_AGENT

          self.api_key    = DEFAULT_API_KEY
          self.format     = DEFAULT_FORMAT
      end

      def configure
          yield self
      end

      def options
        Hash[ * VALID_CONFIG_KEYS.map { |key| [key, send(key)] }.flatten ]
      end

  end # Configuration
end
```

My `Client` class looks like this:

```
module ApiWrapper
    class Client
        attr_accessor *Configuration::VALID_CONFIG_KEYS

        def initialize(options={})
            merged_options = ApiWrapper.options.merge(options)

            Configuration::VALID_CONFIG_KEYS.each do |key|
               send("#{key}=", merged_options[key])
            end
         end

    end # Client
 end
```

My `Season` class looks like this:

```
require 'faraday'
require 'json'

API_URL = "/seasons"

module ApiWrapper
    class Season
        attr_accessor *Configuration::VALID_CONFIG_KEYS
        attr_reader :id

        def initialize(attributes)
            @id = attributes["_links"]["self"]["href"]
            ...
        end

        def self.all
            puts ApiWrapper.api_key
            puts ApiWrapper.endpoint
            conn = Faraday.new
            response = Faraday.get("#{ApiWrapper.endpoint}#{API_URL}/") do |request|
                request.headers['X-Auth-Token'] = "ApiWrapper.api_key"
            end
            seasons = JSON.parse(response.body)
            seasons.map { |attributes| new(attributes) }
        end

    end
end
```

This is the test I am running:

```
def test_it_gives_back_a_seasons
    VCR.use_cassette("season") do
        @config = {
          :api_key    => 'ak',
          :endpoint   => 'http://ep.com',
        }

        client = ApiWrapper::Client.new(@config)
        result = ApiWrapper::Season.all

        # Make sure we got all season data      
            assert_equal 12, result.length

        #Make sure that the JSON was parsed
            assert result.kind_of?(Array)
            assert result.first.kind_of?(ApiWrapper::Season)
    end
  end
```

Because I set the `api_key` via the client to "ak" and the endpoint to "http://ep.com" I would expect `puts` in the `Season` class's `self.all` method to print out "ak" and "http://ep.com", but instead I get the defaults set in the `Configuration` section.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `api_key` accessors you have on `Client` and on `ApiWrapper` are independent. You initialize a `Client` with the key you want, but then `Season` references `ApiWrapper` directly. You've declared `api_key`, etc. accessors in three places: `ApiWrapper::Configuration`, `ApiWrapper` (by extending `Configuration`) and `Client`. You should probably figure out what your use cases are and reduce that down to being in just one place to avoid confusion.

If you're going to have many clients with different API keys as you make different requests, you should inject the client into `Season` and use it instead of `ApiWrapper`. That might look like this:

```
def self.all(client)
  puts client.api_key
  puts client.endpoint
  conn = Faraday.new
  response = Faraday.get("#{client.endpoint}#{API_URL}/") do |request|
      request.headers['X-Auth-Token'] = client.api_key
  end
  seasons = JSON.parse(response.body)
  seasons.map { |attributes| new(attributes) }
end
```

Note that I also replaced the `"ApiWrapper.api_key"` string with the `client.api_key` - you don't want that to be a string anyway.

Having to pass `client` into every request you make is going to get old, so then you might want to pull out something like a `SeasonQuery` class to hold onto it.

If you're only ever going to have one `api_key` and `endpoint` for the duration of your execution, you don't really need the `Client` as you've set it up so far. Just set `ApiWrapper.api_key` directly and continue using it in `Season`.

Comment: I think the second part might be the answer I am looking for, I could make the Client inherit the functionality of the Season and future Classes.  I don't want any future users of the gem to have to always inject the Client in every call to the API.  So instead of calling Season.all( ) to get that list. The user could call Client.getAllSeasonData( )

Comment: Check out the [Twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter). It implements that pattern and is pretty well put together.